# Disable ASP.NET ImageButton in non-IE Browsers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, imagebutton

I have an `<asp:ImageButton />` which has its `enabled` property set to `false`.

This works in Internet Explorer, the button is not 'clickable', but in other browsers you can click it.  However, nothing happens when you click the `imagebutton` in these other browsers.

How can I disable the ability to click the button in browsers outside of Internet Explorer?

Comment: I mean I just wanted to know which language you are using on the back end .. Thanks

Comment: yeah it's C# asp.net  so I set "Enabled="false" in the aspx page

Comment: Try to put it inside a panel control and try to disable the panel control. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand correctly, the `ImageButton` *is* disabled, so it doesn't cause a post back. The issue is that the 'hand' cursor is still displayed in Firefox when putting the mouse over of the `ImageButton`. If this is the case you can change the cursor for the `ImageButton` like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pointer
    {
        cursor:default;
    }
</style>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="~/Images/image.bmp" Enabled="false" />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton1.CssClass = !ImageButton1.Enabled ? "pointer" : "";
}
```

Comment: Won't this cause the poitner to always be default even when it's enabled?

Comment: Good catch, you will have to dynamically add the CssClass property in code behind depending on if the ImageButton is enabled/disabled.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with image button (also how to enable again)

```
                if (cash == true && terms == true)
                {
                    checkOutImageButton.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
                    error = true;
                }
                else
                {                        
                    checkOutImageButton.Attributes.Remove("disabled");
                    error = false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or remove the following in your code-behind file, at the same spot you set `ImageButton1.Enabled = false`.

```
ImageButton1.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: I look at the markup and that's exactly how it renders already.

Comment: and isn't it Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");

Comment: isn't it Attributes.Add("disabled","true"); ?

Comment: Generally I use disabled="disabled" on html input elements (works great!), but I read some where that in backend you need something like Attributes.Add("disabled","true"); so just wanted to clear my doubt, Thanks

Comment: @JackM - this syntax Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled"; is perfectly valid.